# Getting BLOB image and display in html using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

I am facing an issue getting an image from mysql database and displaying on the web page. 
I have a user_image table with userid, image (blob datatype), caption, imagename(name of the image, example, 0101.jpg), time(timestamp of the image upload).
Users can upload image to database and view their images acc to the timestamp.
Any inputs on how to display the image on web page ?
Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","login") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT image,image_name,caption FROM user_image WHERE userid=$userid";
if($query = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        echo $row["image"];
    }
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Here is the code for uploading image into database:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo $_SESSION["userid"];
$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login")or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
 $caption = $_POST['Caption'];


 $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]));
$imageType  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"]);
echo $imageName;
echo $imageType;
if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user_image (userid,timestamp, image, image_name,caption) VALUES (?,now(), ?, ?,?)");
if ($stmt === false) {
trigger_error('Statement failed! ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($con)), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $userid,$imageData, $imageName, $caption);
if ($bind === false) {
trigger_error('Bind param failed!', E_USER_ERROR);}
$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if ($exec === false) {
trigger_error('Statement execute failed! ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)), E_USER_ERROR); }
 }
else
{
echo " only images are allowed";}
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Well some HTML that would constitute a web page would be a good start

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Can u please elaborate a little. I don't understand what u are asking for.

Comment: It would be usful to also see that code that you used to store the image in the table as a blob

Comment: @RiggsFolly - The code used for uploading image has been added. Please check.

Comment: Generally speaking, you dont want to store files in a database. It's slow and unnecessary. A common approach is to copy the uploaded files to a folder with a new essentially random, name. The table stores info like the original name, type, size etc. Displaying the images is simple, since the files already exist on disk. All you need to do is retrieve their location and name, the browser will do the rest.

Comment: And the table schema would be useful as well

Answer (score 0):

i use this for my own site `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($customer->GetCustomer($user)["Customer_image"]).'">'`

where `Customer_image` is blob 
the function GetCustomer($user) is for all information of customer

for my upload i use this

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])){
    $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    fclose($fp);
    $product->UploadImageProduct($id, $name, $data);
}
```